# Adding MySQL accounts via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying find a way to create mysql users with passwords using php code, i.e. without using phpmyadmin, mysql wizard or any else.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you want ot create a database table with columns username and password or you want to insert data into these existing columns using PHP?

Comment: @Husar i want to create database which can content the tables , thanks .

Comment: $me please see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send any of the [account management commands](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/account-management-sql.html) to the database just like any other query.  Of course, it may not be good from a security perspective if your website user account has the privileges in the database to do these things.  (Accounts used for public application purposes should generally be kept to minimum necessary privileges.)  But that's another matter entirely.

Comment: Thanks, how can i use this code ? like this ? mysql_query('CREATE USER 'new_username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password_for_new_username''); ?? or what ??

Comment: @Programmer4me: Well, how do you currently send SQL queries to the database from your PHP code?  It's been a while since I've written anything in PHP, but your example looks accurate.  You'd send the command just like any other query.  (Note however that your example has syntax errors in the string literal, since you start it with a single quote and then use single quotes in the string.)

Comment: Thanks, that means its not need mysql_connect('localhost','root',''); .. right ? Thank you :) .

Comment: @Programmer4me: You'll need to open a connection to the database in order to issue any queries or commands of any kind to it.

Comment: Yes , that's right, but i mean, how can i open a connection, if i dont have any usernames before , should i use "root" as username ? ,, Sorry for more questions, i think this is last :).Thank you :)

Comment: You need to configure MySQL! http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/mysql/set-the-mysql-root-password/

Comment: @Programmer4me: I guess I was assuming you had access to the MySQL database in question.  How is your application structured in the first place?  It's really not recommended to use root from an application context.  You'll want to set up a database user with only the permissions needed for the application.  Then the application would connect to the database and issue commands as that user.  The application wouldn't be creating a user for itself.

Answer (score 4):

you can do this with MySQL Queries:

```
CREATE USER 'new_username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password_for_new_username';
```

See also http://crunchbang.org/archives/2008/04/17/create-mysql-user-accounts-from-the-command-line/

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Thanks, you mean ,, how can i use this code ? like this ? mysql_query('CREATE USER 'new_username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password_for_new_username''); ?? or what ??

Comment: mysql_query("CREATE USER 'myUserName'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mySecretPassword';"); would work, yes.

Comment: It depends on if you're already connected to MySQL. If not, you need to run mysql_connect(). I think you need to learn a bit more basics. Search Google for PHP and MySQL Tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL code for this would be:

```
 CREATE DATABASE db_name; 
 USE db_name;
 CREATE TABLE users(id int not null auto_increment, username varchar(20), password varchar(50));
```

But I really don't know why would you like to do this trough PHP though. Can you please explain why you need this code for?

Also it will definitely help if you have at least basic knowledge of SQL syntax (tutorials should t be hard to find with a simple search...).